# Thinness Or Being Thin?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

> 1.In spite of her thinness, he loves her.
>
> 2.In spite of her being thin, he loves her.

Which sentence is grammatical, thin or thinness? I wanted to know whether "thiness" can use for a person's body.

Comment: You can use *thinness* as a personal attribute. A friend's son used to call his sister *Your Fatness* (a sarcastic version of *Your Majesty*.) Why not? It's perfectly grammatical. Needless to say, she knew how to get her own back.

Comment: Yes,both are fine but in everyday speech, we would probably use her being thin.

Answer (score 1):

Both of your sentences are correct and understandable and have the same meaning.

The use of the *something*-ness suffix makes them equivalent often has the meaning of "having the state of *something*"

> thin**ness** = being thin
>   loud**ness** = being loud
>   awkward**ness** = being awkward
>   open**ness** = begin open

However, it will not work for all adjectives

> <s>smartness</s> *(more usual would be "being smart")*
>   <s>tallness</s>  *(more usually would be "being tall")*